# These credentials do not match our records

Tags: laravel, seed

I have an app with laravel in which, I have different users and different roles. I insert some users, roles, role_user, permission and permission_role in my DB using seeder but, when I try to login using email and password already recorded in DB, I got : These credentials do not match our records.

this is UserTableSeeder :

```
public function run()
{
    //

    $user = [
        [
            'name' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'admin@mail.co',
            'password' => 'passwordadmin'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'president',
            'email' => 'President@mail.co',
            'password' => 'passwordpresident'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'utilisateur1',
            'email' => 'utilisateur1@mail.co',
            'password' => 'passworduser'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'utilisateur2',
            'email' => 'utilisateur2@mail.co',
            'password' => 'passworduser'
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
        User::create($value);
    }
}
```

RoleTableSeeder :

```
public function run()
{
    //

    $role = [
        [
            'name' => 'admin',
            'display_name' => 'Administrateur',
            'description' => 'Administrateur du système'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'president',
            'display_name' => 'Président',
            'description' => 'President de la commune'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'utilisateur_normal',
            'display_name' => 'membre du conseil',
            'description' => 'membre du conseil'
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($role as $key => $value) {
        Role::create($value);
    }
}
```

RoleUserTableSeeder :

```
public function run()
{
    //

    DB::table( 'role_user' )->insert([
        [ 'user_id' => 6, 'role_id' => 4 ],
        [ 'user_id' => 7, 'role_id' => 5 ],
        [ 'user_id' => 8, 'role_id' => 6 ],
        [ 'user_id' => 9 , 'role_id' => 6 ],            
    ]);

}
```

Models I have : User, Role, Permission.

Any idea please ?

Comment: You need to insert the password encrypted into the database: `'password' => bcrypt('passworduser'),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Troyer said, you need to hash them with bcrypt. Laravel provides a handy wrapper with \Hash::make($str).

It is extremely bad practice to have your passwords in plaintext.

You need to run your seeder like this:

```
public function run()
{
    $users = [
        [
            'name' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'admin@mail.co',
            'password' => \Hash::make('passwordadmin') // Hash them in order to make use of \Auth library (and more importantly, in order not to be a dick to your users)
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'president',
            'email' => 'President@mail.co',
            'password' => \Hash::make('passwordpresident')
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'utilisateur1',
            'email' => 'utilisateur1@mail.co',
            'password' => \Hash::make('passworduser')
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'utilisateur2',
            'email' => 'utilisateur2@mail.co',
            'password' => \Hash::make('passworduser')
        ]
    ];
    User::create($users); // Import them with 1 query for performance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks you are not hashing your passwords into your database, you need to use `bycript`:

```
public function run()
{
    //

$user = [
    [
        'name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin@mail.co',
        'password' => bcrypt('passwordadmin')
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'president',
        'email' => 'President@mail.co',
        'password' => bcrypt('passwordpresident')
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'utilisateur1',
        'email' => 'utilisateur1@mail.co',
        'password' => bcrypt('passworduser')
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'utilisateur2',
        'email' => 'utilisateur2@mail.co',
        'password' => bcrypt('passworduser')
    ]
];

foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    User::create($value);
}
}
```

You can see more seeder examples on the [oficial seeder Laravel documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding)

Comment: You are right the problem was the hashing, but when I tried using bcrypt it didn't work. I used " \Hash::make('passwordadmin') " instead. Thank you

Comment: @Naj esencially `\Hash::make()` and `bcrypt()` are the same, `bcrypt()` is a Laravel helper function that calls `Hash::make()`, just I like it more because it looks much cleaner :)